# Velocity templates - Syntax for passing variables to methods

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to construct a "friendly" email message based on a database lookup and cannot seem to nail down the right syntax for the following:

```
System.out.println(TagFunctions.getConstantValue(4, "val1", Integer.parseInt(selectedFiling.getRejectionReason())));
```

I realize that I could just evaluate this within my class file, but the desire is to be able to make database changes without deploying again.

I believe that I am missing some curly braces here, but I nothing that I have tried has worked.

```
$tagFunctions.getConstantValue(4, "val1", $Integer.parseInt($selectedFiling.rejectionReason))
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you did:

```
context.put("Integer", Integer.class);
```

then `$Integer` is not a valid reference in your template.

Comment: Same goes for other references too, of course.  And all methods must be declared public within public classes.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the actual code and/or stack trace.

Without more information, here's my first guess. Are you populating the context properly such that you can call static methods on TagFunctions and Integer? See this link for more info: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#supportforstaticclasses

Comment: I believe that the context is set appropriately as this line works and makes reference to the same objects being used in the problematic line:

$tagFunctions.getFilingTypeLongString(${selectedFiling.filingType})

Comment: Actually this second example does not refer to $Integer, whereas the line you say you're having trouble with calls $Integer.parseInt. It's much easier to help if you post the stack trace and a code sample. Otherwise everybody will have to guess what the actual problem is.